# How to rip CDs in FLAC format using Banshee?

Tags: music, banshee, cd

By default Banshee rips CDs in Ogg Vorbis format. I prefer to rip my CDs in FLAC format. I can't find a setting anywhere to make Banshee rip to FLAC.

Is this possible? How do I do it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In Banshee's Edit->Preferences select the "Source Specific" tab, and then select "Audio CDs" under "Source". Under "Input Format" you should be able to select "Free Lossless Audio Codec (FLAC)".

Note: you will need the [libflac8](http://packages.ubuntu.com/p/libflac8)[image: install libflac8] package installed, but this should be installed by default on Ubuntu as part of the GStreamer "good" plugins ([gstreamer0.10-plugins-good](http://packages.ubuntu.com/p/gstreamer0.10-plugins-good)[image: install gstreamer0.10-plugins-good]
).

[image: FLAC setting settings screenshot]

Comment: I have no idea how I failed to find that! :P

Comment: Mine was actually on FLAC already and I don't remember changing it...

Comment: I missed it too, the Banshee documentation needs updating.